# how to export some thing like {variable} literally in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In my document, I have some word like a_table_name_{variable}, and I just want it to export to HMTL to a_table_name_{variable} literally,
but when export it error out. And if I remove {variable} ghen it could export correctly. SO how to make it export literally (as it is)?

update:
If I use 
a_table_name_ {variable}, then it can export without any issue.

But if use a_table_name_{variable}, it will throw the error of
Wrong type argument: stringp, (subscript (:begin 17627 :end 17631 :use-brackets-p nil :contents-begin 17628 :contents-end 17631 ...) #("Key" 0 3 (:parent #0)))

So looks like I can't use _{variable}, but could use _ {variable}

Comment: Could you give the error, or what the output is, and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: The error is Wrong type argument: stringp, (subscript (:begin 17627 :end 17631 :use-brackets-p nil :contents-begin 17628 :contents-end 17631 ...) #("Key" 0 3 (:parent #0)))

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  If you start emacs with -Q does it still happen?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at org documentation, with `C-h i m org`. Your question is answered in 'Markup/Structural markup/Emphasis and monospace':

```
You can make words *bold*, /italic/, _underlined_, ‘=verbatim=’ and
‘~code~’, and, if you must, ‘+strike-through+’.  Text in the code and
verbatim string is not processed for Org mode specific syntax, it is
exported verbatim.
```